# Why don't these morphisms extend?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, projective-schemes

This is part of exercise 16.5.A in Vakil's notes (http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf). To give an example of why the assumptions in the curve-to-projective extension theorem (16.5.1) are necessary, he asks you to show the following morphisms $C \backslash p \to Y$ do not extend to morphisms $C \to Y$:

1. $C = Y = \mathbb{A}^1_k$, $p=0$, and the map is $t \mapsto t^{-1}$.
2. $C = \mathbb{A}^2_k$, $Y = \mathbb{P}^1_k$, $p=(0,0)$, and the map is $(x,y) \mapsto [x : y]$.
3. Same as 2 but $C = \mathrm{Spec}(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3))$.

I completely understand the first one, and intuitively why the second and third should fail, but don't know how to prove it. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: (2) Approach to $(0,0)$ along $(0,y)$. The map is constant along that line, equal to $[0:y]=[0:1]$ and that is the limit. Approach $(0,0)$ along $(x,0)$. The maps output is $[x:0]=[1:0]$.

Comment: Is there a way to rephrase this in the language of schemes? I'd prefer not to take limits.
For example, if the morphism were to extend, say to $\pi : \mathbb{A}^2_k \to \mathbb{P}^1_k$, then it would correspond to two global sections of the line bundle $\pi^* \mathscr{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ without common zeros, namely $\pi^* X, \pi^* Y$ where $X, Y$ are projective coordinates. Since it's an extension, we must have $\pi^*X = x$ and $\pi^*Y = y$ (this is sketchy), but this means that $V(x)$ maps to $V(X)$ and $V(y)$ maps to $V(Y)$, which can't happen since $V(X) \cap V(Y) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Yes, you can Frenchify it. Without any gain in understanding, though. Composing $\pi$ with $f_y:\mathbb{A}_k^1\to\mathbb{A}_k^2$ given by $k[x,y]\to k[x,y]/(y)$, you get a map $\pi\circ f_y$ sending $0\neq p\in\mathbb{A}_k^1$ sent to $[0:1]$. Therefore, $\pi\circ f_y$ should send $0$ to $[0:1]$. Doing the same with $f_x:\mathbb{A}_k^1\to\mathbb{A}_k^2$ given by $k[x,y]\to k[x,y]/(x)$ you get that $0$ should be sent to $[1:0]$.

Answer (score 0):

As 2) has been adressed in the comments, this answer will address 3).

Consider the function on the image of $C$ given by $[x:y]\mapsto y/x$. If the morphism extended to all of $C$, $y/x$ would be a function in $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$, which is clearly wrong.

What's going on here is that singular curves are non-normal, and we're picking an element which is integral over the coordinate algebra but not contained in it - this is only possible when the curve is not normal.